# How do I know which Command Prompt is related to a specific PID?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, pid

I have multiple Python programs running in separate Command Prompt windows in order to find a memory leak (the specifics are irrelevant).

While watching the processes on `Task Manager > Resource Monitor > Memory`, I saw one instance that is having the memory leak issue.

[image]

However, now I don't know which Command Prompt window is having the problem.

**Is there a way to know which cmd window is related to a specific PID while the programs are still running?**

Comment: What is different about them? Task Manager has a command line column that you can turn on if that is the difference. In Details View, right click the column headers and choose Select Columns and choose Command Line.

Comment: PS there is nothing in your screenshot that suggests its in a command prompt. Perhaps you mean consoles.

Comment: Option: get ProcessExplorer from [sysinternals-now-part-of-MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) rightclick the process in the list, and use Window>BringToFront or >Maximize to visually highlight it.

Comment: @user1292580 I thought Command Prompt and consoles were used interchangeably, I meant consoles, yes. And thanks for the tip, I was not aware of the Command Line column, unfortunately in my case all runs were from the same program with the same parameters. I was redirecting the output to file using `... > run_0.txt`. I could use some slightly different parameters that wouldn't make an actual difference, then your solution would work, thanks!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Looks like that answers my question (I haven't taken a look at it yet), thank you

Comment: Using `wmic` to start programs gives you the PID. Its important to know if you are using a command prompt in your console. As `cmd.exe` implements command line redirection. `>` means nothing outside of `cmd.exe`. eg `wmic process call create notepad.exe`.

Comment: istConsole.exe - similar to Unix's $SHLVL variable - list the processes in the current console and returns an errorlevel saying how many https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/listconsoleexe-list-processes-in.html may show you more in action.